Solving PDE $u_{t} + u^3u_{x} = 0$ with different initial conditions
I'm trying to solve this excercise:
$u_{t} + u^3u_{x} = 0 \quad,x\in \mathbb{R} \space,t>0$
with the following initial conditions:
$(i)\quad u(x,0) = \sqrt[3]{x} \quad \quad \quad (ii)\quad u(x,0) = - \sqrt[3]{x}$
The requests are the following:

Deterimine the characteristics and the solutions for the Cauchy problem with the previous initial condition.


Determine the maximal domain A of definition of the solutions as continuous functions: explain if they are of class $C^1(A)$ and satisfy the Entropy Condition.

Now, I know I have to use the Method of Characteristics and I found (after first calculation) that the characteristic lines along which $u$ is constant are the following:
$\quad \quad x = u^{3}_{0}t + x_{0}$
where $x_{0}$ is the initial condition for x and $u_{0}$ is the constant value of $u$ at time $t = 0$ along each charcteristic line.
Up until now everything is clear to me. Then I started analyzing each initial condition:
$1^{st}\space Case: \quad u(x,0) = \sqrt[3]{x}$
I find that the solution is:
$u(x,t) = \sqrt[3]\frac{x}{1+t} \quad , for \space x\in \mathbb{R}\space,\space t>0$
From this I can tell that the maximal domain $A$ is $A = { \mathbb{R} \times (0,\inf) }$ and then I verified that $u(x,t)$ is not of class $C^1(A)$ since its partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ is not continuous at $x = 0$.
Therefore, $u$ defined as above is a weak solution (correct me if I am wrong) and satisfies the entropy condition because $u$ is continuous in its domain of definition and it hasn't got any shock waves (on the contrary, it has rarefaction waves).
Do you think that up until now everything is correct?
For what concern instead the second case with
$u(x,0) = -\sqrt[3]x$
I achieved that the solution is
$u(x,t) = -\sqrt[3]\frac{x}{1-t} \quad , for \space x\in \mathbb{R}\space,\space t>0$
From this I can tell that the maximal domain $A$ is $A = { \mathbb{R} \times (0,1) }$ and then I verified that $u(x,t)$ is not of class $C^1(A)$ since its partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ is not continuous at $x = 0$.
Also here I can tell that $u$ defined as above is a weak solution of our problem (also here correct me if I'm wrong), but, in this case, it has shock waves 'converging' to the point $t = 1$.
Looking throughout the Net, I've found many excercises similar to this one, but everyone uses different approaches.
At first, I thought that it satisfies the entropy condition because $u$ is continuous in its domain of definition, even if I'm not completely sure it is a valid argument.
Then, I tried to very the entropy condition by using R.-H. Jump Condition and then the Oleinik's Entropy Condition, but I don't know how to proceed.
Could you please help me find the correct steps to follow (I accept also general steps that can be used as a strategy for this type of excercise) to solve this problem?
Thanks you a lot guys.
